# Convert a string to an an array-like string to an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, eval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert a Ruby string with brackets to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38409/how-do-i-convert-a-ruby-string-with-brackets-to-an-array)

In ruby, how to transform a string to an array when this string looks-like an array declaration?
Is there an equivalent of "eval" methods? I would like to avoid the split method is this case.

Eg.

myString = "[['joey','male','joey@email.com],['jenny','female','jenny@email.com']]"

Comment: 'joey@email.com should be 'joey@email.com'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval` would do it. However I would recommend using something like `JSON.parse` if the data is coming from an untrusted source (i.e. the Internet).