# Converting array/hash to string and converting that string back to array/hash in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I had this array lets say,

```
array = [{'key' => 0},1]
```

so now `array[0]['key']` has value `0`.
When I convert it to string like this:

```
array.to_s
```

Now the array is not an array its a string which is like this:

```
"[{'key' => 0},1]"
```

If I do `array[0]` now, it will output `[`

I want to convert this back to array so that I can use `array[0]['key']` again.

Full Code:

```
array = [{'key' => 0},1]
array = array.to_s
puts array[0]['key'] #Should output 0 but it does not output anything
```

The thing is that I have already saved stuff like that in the database, so now I need to use that stuff back, so the only way is to parse the saved string (which was actually an array).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a Ruby string with brackets to an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38409/how-do-i-convert-a-ruby-string-with-brackets-to-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string = "[{'key' => 0},1]"
array = eval string
array[0]['key']  # => 0
```

Comment: using `eval` in this case is a bad practice.

Comment: I see, thank you for the warning, could you elaborate more please?

Comment: You can read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902744/when-is-eval-in-ruby-justified) question

Comment: @Ilya well I just need to correct my database so I guess its fine. I am not using this on permanent basis.